# File shares inacessible after server update

Tags: windows-server-2016, file-sharing

So I applied the 2021-9 updates on one of our Windows 2016 Server yesterday.
The server was configured with a File Sharing role and the share had been working smoothly for more than a year, no glitch whatsoever.

Since the update has been applied, the windows share is not accessible from outside computers (belonging to the same domain and networked using simple unmanaged switches).
I cannot figure out what the problem might be.
Here is the current status of the installation:

- Server is hosted as a VM on a Citrix Xen server 8.2. All service packages are installed.
- The share can be accessed locally from the windows server involved through file explorer.
- I can ping the machine from other computers (IP address or FQDN)
- Other network related services on the machine seem to work fine (remote desktop access, ...).
- I enabled filesharing from the "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings" menu (network discovery and file sharing are enabled).
- The firewall is currently shut down on the problematic server
- I can see the server in the network section of my File explorer, however I received a 0x80070035 error (windows cannot access \xxxx) if I double click on it.

  - SMB is enabled on the computer as are all required services (UPnP Device Host, Function Discovery Provider Host, Function Discovery Ressource Publiation, SSDP Discovery)
- I tried to completely reset the ethernet settings without any effect
- I tried to roll-back the updates without any effect
- I tried removing the share and recreating it without any effect
- I scrolled through the Windows Systems and Application logs but I did not find anything special ...

Help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I guess I found the answer here since I found out, that connection was working from the problematic server using localhost, FQDN but not the IPV4 address

https://superuser.com/questions/1240213/cannot-connect-to-windows-share-via-local-network-ip-address-but-can-by-localho